# PHP-FPM Docker container terminates right after start in AWS ECS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker

I am trying to deploy containerized Nginx + PHP-FPM application to the AWS ECS service. In my local Docker compose setup everything works flawlessly. However, when I create a task definition in AWS ECS and try to launch task, my PHP-FPM container attempts to start and exits immediately within the same second. I am running PHP-FPM container as non-root user. Here are some details:

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:2.6 AS composer
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine AS php-base
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

RUN apk upgrade --no-cache \
    && apk add --no-cache --update --virtual buildDeps gcc=13.2.1_git20231014-r0 \
    make=4.4.1-r2 g++=13.2.1_git20231014-r0 autoconf=2.71-r2 linux-headers=6.5-r0 fcgi=2.4.2-r4

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
RUN deluser --remove-home www-data && addgroup -g ${GID} www-data && adduser -u ${UID} -D --ingroup www-data www-data

COPY . /var/www/html
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
#Install PHP healhcheck script
RUN wget -q -O /usr/local/bin/php-fpm-healthcheck \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renatomefi/php-fpm-healthcheck/master/php-fpm-healthcheck \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/php-fpm-healthcheck \
&& echo "pm.status_path = /status" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

#HEALTHCHECK --start-period=3s --interval=5s --timeout=2s CMD php-fpm-healhcheck || exit 1

FROM php-base AS php-prod

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini" \
    && composer install --no-ansi --no-dev --no-interaction --no-plugins --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader

FROM php-base AS php-dev

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini" \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=develop,debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && composer install

FROM php-prod AS portfolio-prod

COPY docker/php-fpm/php-conf.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/
RUN mkdir -p /files/profile && mkdir -p /files/portfolio && chown -R www-data:www-data /files
USER www-data

FROM php-dev AS portfolio-dev

COPY docker/php-fpm/php-conf.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/
RUN mkdir -p /files/profile && mkdir -p /files/portfolio && chown -R www-data:www-data /files
USER www-data
```

My task definition JSON file:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:825247853638:task-definition/Mariia-portfolio-task:4",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "nginx",
            "image": "825247853638.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mariia_portfolio_nginx:latest",
            "cpu": 512,
            "memory": 256,
            "memoryReservation": 128,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "nginx-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "php-fpm",
                    "condition": "START"
                }
            ],
            "workingDirectory": "/var/www/html",
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/Mariia-portfolio-task",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "php-fpm",
            "image": "825247853638.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mariia_portfolio_php_fpm:latest",
            "cpu": 1536,
            "memory": 512,
            "memoryReservation": 256,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "workingDirectory": "/var/www/html",
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/Mariia-portfolio-task",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "Mariia-portfolio-task",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::825247853638:role/ECSTaskRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::825247853638:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 4,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.container-ordering"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "2048",
    "memory": "800",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2024-03-09T16:21:08.835Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::825247853638:user/dmytro",
    "tags": []
}
```

Cloudwatch logs:

```
2024-03-12T19:44:26.996+01:00   [12-Mar-2024 18:44:26] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root

2024-03-12T19:44:26.996+01:00   [12-Mar-2024 18:44:26] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1

2024-03-12T19:44:26.997+01:00   [12-Mar-2024 18:44:26] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

2024-03-12T19:44:27.536+01:00
[12-Mar-2024 18:44:27] NOTICE: Finishing ...

[12-Mar-2024 18:44:27] NOTICE: Finishing ...

2024-03-12T19:44:27.536+01:00
[12-Mar-2024 18:44:27] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated!

I have tried running it locally (works fine), tried to compile the production version of the image and use `docker run` to check the container. Also, tried to play around with the task definition (disable some volume mounts for example). Also, I tried to use AWS ECS service, as well as launch the task directly - same result.